# How to specify global markup font-size or other property in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

Can I do this in Lilypond? I believe it's possible, however I could not find anything in docs about this.

My question is, instead of repeating like this:

```
g16-\markup {\tiny\underline\typewriter 1/16 }
g8-\markup {\tiny\underline\typewriter 1/8 }
g4-\markup {\tiny\underline\typewriter 1/4}
```

Is it possible to have those attributes grouped, then used simply where one would need them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several solutions to this. Here's another suggestion:

```
tut = #(define-scheme-function
          (parser location text)
          (string?)
          #{\markup { \tiny \underline \typewriter #text }
          #})

{ g16 -\tut "1/16" }
```

Comment: Maybe this could even be put in an include file and re-used for other scores?

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward way is to define a markup command:

```
#(define-markup-command (tut layout props m) (markup?)
  (interpret-markup layout props
   #{ \markup \tiny \underline \typewriter #m #}))

{
  g16-\markup \tut 1/16
  g8-\markup \tut 1/8
  g4-\markup \tut 1/4
}
```

There is another already upvoted answer that is quite simpler.  Unfortunately, simpler than LilyPond would permit.

Comment: Defining a function is such a pain for a language based on an functional engine.

Comment: Is there any guide on how to learn to write these?

Comment: Here's a link to the LilyPond documentation: http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/extending/new-markup-command-definition

Answer (score 1):

For a relatively simple approach, you can (as of 2.19.80) define a markup command using the syntax

```
\markup tut = \markup \tiny \underline \typewriter \etc
{ g16-\markup \tut 1/16 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to temporarily save typing:

```
\version "2.19.26"

\markupMap TextScriptEvent.text \markup \tiny \underline \typewriter \etc
{
  g16-"1/16"
  g8-"1/8"
  g4-"1/4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a relatively simple approach, you can define a macro:

tut = \tiny\underline\typewriter

g16-\markup {\tut 1/16 }

Comment: You surely can define a macro, but these two lines of code will almost certainly not work just like this.